# Float and double - Significand numbers- Mantissa POV?

Tags: c#, floating-point, double, ieee-754

With *Single* precision (32 bits): the bits division goes [*like this*](http://www.dspguide.com/ch4/3.htm) :

[image]

So we have *23* bits of mantissa/Significand .

So we can represent 2^23 numbers (via 23 bits ) :  which is `8388608` --> which is 7 digit long.

**BUT**

I was reading that the mantissa is normalized (*the leading digit in the mantissa will always be a 1*)  - so the pattern is actually `1.mmm` and **only** the `mmm` is represented in the mantissa.

for example : look here :

[image]

0.75 is represented but it's actually 1.75

**Question #1**

So basically it adds 1 more precision digit....no ?

If so then we have 8 Significand  !

So *why* does msdn says : 7 ?

[image]

**Question #2**

In double there are 52 bits for mantissa. (0..51)

If I add 1 for the normalized mantissa so its 2^53 possibilites which is : `9007199254740992` ( 16 digits)

and MS does say : 15-16 :

[image]

Why is this inconsistency ? am I missing something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't add one more *decimal* digit - just a single binary digit. So instead of 23 bits, you have 24 bits. This is handy, because the only number you can't represent as starting with a one is zero, and that's a special value.

In short, you're not looking at `2 ^ 24` (that would be a decimal number, base-10) - you're looking at `2 ^ (-24)`. That's the most important difference between `float`-`double` and `decimal`. `decimal` is what you imagine floats to be, ie. a simple exponent-shifted, base-10 number. `float` and `double` aren't that.

Now, decimal digits versus binary digits is a tricky matter. You're mistaken in your understanding that the precision has anything to do with the `2 ^ 24` figure - that would only be true if you were talking about e.g. the `decimal` type, which actually stores decimal values as decimal point offsets of a normal (huge-ass) integer.

Just like `1 / 3` cannot be written in decimal (`0.333333...`), many simple decimal numbers can't be represented in a float precisely (`0.2` is the typical example). `decimal` doesn't have a problem with that - it's just `2` shifted one digit to the right, easy peasy. For floats, however, you have to represent this value as a sum of negative powers of two - `0.5`, `0.25`, `0.125` ... The same would apply in the opposite direction if `2` wasn't a factor of `10` - every finite binary "decimal" can be represented with finite precision in decimal.

Now, in fact, `float` can easily represent a number with 24 decimal digits - it just has to be `2 ^ (-24)` - a number you're not going to encounter in your usual day job, and a weird number in decimal. So where does the `7` (actually more like `7.22...`) come from? Simple, just do a decimal logarithm of `2 ^ (-24)`.

The fact that it seems that `0.2` can be represented "exactly" in a `float` is simply because everytime you e.g. convert it to a string, you're rounding. So, even though the number isn't `0.2` exactly, it ends up that way when you convert it to a decimal number.

All this means that when you need decimal precision, you want to use `decimal`, as simple as that. This is not because it's a better base for calculations, it's simply because humans use it, and they will not be happy if your application gives different results from what they calculate on a piece of paper - especially when dealing with money. Accountants are very focused on having everything correct to the least significant digit.

Floats are used where it's not about decimal precision, but rather about generally having some sort of precision - this makes them well suited for physics calculations and similar, because you don't actually care about having the number come up the same in decimal - you're working with a given precision, and you're going to get that - 24 significant binary "decimals".

Comment: it doesn't matter  - it's a digit. I already know that decimal is _decimal_ floating point vs float /double which is  _binary_ floating point. but still - both represents values. 95% of your answer explain not related info ( 0.333 , decimal vs float , minus at power , humans read decimal..... ). 2^24 vs 2^-24  , it doesn't matter - the job of the mantissa is to provide significant numbers.

Comment: @RoyiNamir The job of the mantissa in a float is to provide significant *binary* digits. `1.1111111f.ToString("f10")` will give you `"1.111111"` - the "guaranteed" 7 decimal digits. However, `1.1920928955078125.ToString("f20")` will give you 17 decimal digits. Your question makes it pretty clear you *don't* understand the difference between `decimal` and `float` (`So we can represent 2^23 numbers (via 23 bits ) : which is 8388608 --> which is 7 digit long.`).

Comment: with 23 bits I can represent max value : `2^23 - 1`  - it doesnt matter where i put the dot. that's the exponent job. anyway -  can you go to chat ? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51161/room-for-royi-namir-and-luaan

Answer (score 1):

The implied leading 1 adds one more *binary* digit of precision, not decimal.